# Force exit code zero for windows command line commands

Tags: windows, cmd, exit-code

How can I force the exit code to be zero for a windows cmd command without changing the way it behaves

The linux equivalent of what is mean is

```
netstat -an | grep 12035 || true
```

Something I tried is

```
C:\>netstat -ano | find "25000" | exit 0
```

Though it forces exit code 0, it does not show the desired output when successful

Eg:

```
C:\>netstat -ano | find "25000"
TCP    0.0.0.0:25000          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4832

C:\>netstat -ano | find "25000" | exit 0
```

Any idea if there is a way?

Comment: The linux command works fine in its current form, if that was what you are referring to. If you are referring to the windows command, && exit 0 will just execute an exit command

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
netstat -an | find "25000" || ver>nul
```

If the `find` command raises errorlevel, execute a command that resets it., in this case the `ver` command is used and its output discarded